# How to Get SharePoint PowerShell to use .NET 2

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, config

I'm having a couple of problems with PowerShell. First, the PS configuration installed by SharePoint 2010 keeps popping this message:

The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.

I've googled that, and given everybody and their second cousin Sharepoint_Shell_Access to the config DB, with no luck. So, I wanted to try some of the PS commands. In this case, however, I'm getting a different error:

Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.17929 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime.

I get that SP can't use .NET 4.0 or 4.5, but I can't find any suggestions on how to get PS to use the "right" version of .NET. I've found some references for something called PowerGUI, and changing the psgui.exe.config, but I don't have that.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve the .NET version problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you install powershell v3, version 2 is still available in side by side mode. In order to use the SharePoint snapin, you must launch v2 like this:

```
powershell -v 2
```

Then you can load the snapin for SharePoint.

For reference, here is the output from invoking PowerShell v2 from Windows 8 cmd.exe:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>powershell.exe -version 2
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.6387
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1


PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> [Environment]::Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      50727  6387
```

Comment: @EoRaptor013 - then you're doing it wrong. I use this technique every day. Look at the example above (kindly added by @goyuix)

Comment: You're right; I did it wrong. Put the command-line switch in the wrong place. Correcting that mistake, registered PS with the .NET 2.0 environment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah... if you don't make -version (or -v) the first parameter to powershell.exe, it won't work. Not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

One can add the command line switch `-version 2` to the `Start Menu` item by right clicking it, selecting `Properties`, and editing the string in the `Target` field.

This fix also clears up the erroneous message

> The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId
>   are not registered.

I was getting this message when launching SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.

Comment: If you think that the question was an excellent post, please do an up-vote.